# How to redirect localhost/test/test.php to redirect localhost/test/test

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Here is my code of .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On**RewriteBase /RewriteRule ^test/?$ test.php [L,NC]
```

but it is not redirecting me to "test".Is there any mistake in .htacces or I have to do some Apache configuration changes.
Thanks

Comment: Is it your `.htaccess` in /test/ directory?

Comment: yes this is my .htaccess

Comment: I would recommend that you use virtual hosts, this will save you some trouble when working on localhost http://ailoo.net/2008/07/set-up-multiple-virtual-hosts-on-xampp-for-windows/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks Boy..this one is best

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```